# no neato laser scan with hector_slam

Tags: ros, lidar, hector-slam, bagfile, neato

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to get a laser scan in rviz with neato lidar tutorial.  But when I try to get a laser scan with hector_slam there isn't a scan in rviz.  I am trying to use hector_map with out odometer.  I have changed the launch file to reflect that ( I think).  Are there other settings that I will have to change to get a good bag file?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197424/no-neato-laser-scan-with-hector_slam/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-11-16**:
This is the warning that I get: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.002542 seconds of waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure what the problem is but maybe you want to try my launch file. It's working fine over here with XV-11 and hector_slam.

Hmm I cant post it as code because the xml seems to get messed up and I can't upload files yet, so here it is on pastebin:

[hector_launch](http://pastebin.com/pLCa260k)

Before you run it you just have to start your Neato driver manually, didn't include that yet...

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [tinytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/20467/tinytron/) with karma: 45 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-11-18**:
Thank you!  I will give it a try.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-11-18**:
This is what I am getting with your launch file: roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/rviz].
Please check all  'name' attributes to make sure they are unique.
Also check that $(anon id) use different ids.

**Comment by [tinytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/20467/tinytron/) on 2014-11-27**:
Did you try to remove anything related to RViz in the launch file to see if it starts then? You could then still record a bag and play it afterwards?